# How to disable Postal/Zip code for African Countries on Woocommerce Checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to disable postal/zip code for African Countries when they select an African country, it's working for some and not working for some. 
**Working**: Nigeria,Angola 
**Not Work**: Cameroon, Ghana etc.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script>

    /* Disable African Countries from checkout */
    jQuery(function($){
    $(document.body).on('change', 'select[name=billing_country]', function(){
        let africanCountries  =['DZ','AO','BJ','BW','BF','BI','CM','CV','CF','TD','KM','CG','CD','DJ','EG','GQ','ER','ET','GA','GM','GH','GN','GW','CI','KE','LS','LR','LY','MG','MW','ML','MR','MU','MA','MZ','NA','NE','NG','RW','SN','SC','SL','SO','ZA','SS','SD','SZ','TZ','TG','TN','UG','ZM','ZW'];
        
        let selectedCountry = $(this).val();
        if(africanCountries.indexOf(selectedCountry) !== -1){
            $('#postalCode').prop('required',false);        
        }else{
            $("#postalCode").prop('required',true);
        }
        
        
    });
});

</script>

<?php } );
```

Comment: You forgot a `#` before postalCode in the else.

Comment: @James I have updated it but not still working.

Comment: Seems to work fine assuming a correct HTML structure - https://jsfiddle.net/b5xLznsm/